# Integrated Windows Authentication in ABP framework

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, aspnetboilerplate

I'm attempting to use ABP with Windows Authentication rather than Table-based authentication.

The plan is to have the framework:

1. Detect that the website is in a Windows security context and bypass
   the login page.
2. Then associate Windows Identity/Roles and use those to map the
   Roles/Permissions defined in the database.

I did not see anything in the documentation regarding this Windows-integrated approach.

If anyone has done this previously, I appreciate any tips.

I think my best bet would be to use Policy-based authorization. So where the controllers currently use ABP auth attributes, I'll revert back to the normal ASP.NET ones.

e.g. `[Authorize(Policy = "MyAppAdmin")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the spirit of sharing here is how i managed to circumvent the use of the login screen for a Window Authenticated context.

1. make the Login panel hidden and set some dummy data on the username/password controls (the dummy data is not actually used).
2. in the js file run the login action immediately (no user interaction)

   ```js
   abp.ajax({
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       url: $loginForm.attr('action'),
       data: $loginForm.serialize()
   });
   ```
3. In the AccountController:

   ```cs
   var windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
   loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress = windowsIdentity.Name;

   var count = (from x in windowsIdentity.Claims where x.Value == "myclaim" select x).Count();

   if (count == 0)
   {
       throw _abpLoginResultTypeHelper.CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt(AbpLoginResultType.InvalidUserNameOrEmailAddress, loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress, null);
   }
   ```
4. Create an ExternalAuthSource as described in the answer above. We will always return `true` becuase the real authentication is already done.

   ```cs
   public override Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, Tenant tenant)
   {
       return Task.FromResult(true);
   }
   ```

   It has the added advantage that the authenticated user is created by the ABP Framework automatically. The Role the new user is assigned depends on the which role is the `Default` - see Table `AbpUserRoles`.

Hopefully this helps somebody trying to use the framework in a Windows-Authenticated context.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. what about signing in from out of intranet network. try to login with your mobile to see if you get the same result. I guess you cannot retrieve WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

Comment: if a user signs out of the network then their windows session ends and along with it the web app (ie the user clicks 'log-off' on windows start menu).  Right now I have no way of logging into our network (intra-net) using a mobile device.

Comment: Do you have a sample project you could share?

Answer (score 3):

To login the user thru official AspNet Boilerplate API (to have roles and other stuffs) you can use external authentication. It is exactly what you are looking for;

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication

Comment: It might be possible to even do away with the login form in a Windows integrated / authenticated context. I'm not sure how difficult it would be though...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do what John suggested, but I had to make a few changes, so this is how I did it.

"angular\src\account\login\login.component.ts"

```
class LoginComponent {    
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.authenticateModel.userNameOrEmailAddress = 'foo';
    this.loginService.authenticateModel.password = 'bar';
    this.login();
  }
}
```

"aspnet-core\src\ProjectName.Core\Authentication\AlwaysTrue\AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource.cs"

```
public class AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource: DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>, ITransientDependency
{
  public override string Name => "AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource";

  public override Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, Tenant tenant)
  {
    return Task.FromResult(true);
  }
}
```

"aspnet-core\src\ProjectName.Core\ProjectNameCoreModule.cs"

```
public class ProjectNameCoreModule : AbpModule
{
  public override void PreInitialize()
  {
    Configuration.Modules.Zero().UserManagement.ExternalAuthenticationSources.Add<AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource>();
  }
}
```

"aspnet-core\src\ProjectName.Web.Core\Controllers\TokenAuthController.cs"

```
public class TokenAuthController : ProjectNameControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<AuthenticateResultModel> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel model)
  {
    var windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    model.UserNameOrEmailAddress = windowsIdentity.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Replace("\\","");

    var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(...)
  }
}
```