# In AspBoilerPlate - Unauthorized error when calling from Angular when Windows Authentication is On

Tags: windows-authentication, aspnetboilerplate

Have already raised this before and thought I have addressed it as per what suggested on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820965/integrated-windows-authentication-in-abp-framework) and [THIS](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10921&p=27700&hilit=windows%20authentication#p27700) but seems not!
I am using ABP template (Angular and ASP .NET CORE Application) on Full .Net Framework. I simply want to use Windows Authentication to Authenticate user.

I added [Authorize] to the `Authenticate` in the `TokenAuthController` and have finally got the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` populated but only when I call the `Authenticate` from the Swagger (`http://localhost:21021/swagger`). But I am getting Unauthorized error when calling the method from Angular (`login.service.ts`):

> POST http://localhost:21021/api/TokenAuth/Authenticate 401 (Unauthorized)

Here is the steps I have taken so far:

1. Changed launchSetting.json:

   ```
    "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:21021/",
       "sslPort": 0
      }  
     },
   ```
2. Added ExternalAuthenticationSource:

   ```
    public class WindowsAuthSource : DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>, ITransientDependency
   {
   public override string Name
   {
       get { return "Windows Authentication"; }
   }

   public override Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, Tenant tenant)
   {
       return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
   }
   ```
3. Added it to CoreModule:
     `Configuration.Modules.Zero().UserManagement.ExternalAuthenticationSources.Add<WindowsAuthSource>();`

4.Adjust AuthConfigurer:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

5. Adjust StartUp.cs:

   ```
       services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
       {
           iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "WINDOWS";
           iis.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
       });
   ```
6. Changed Authenticate method in the TokenAuthController:

   ```
     public async Task<AuthenticateResultModel> Authenticate([FromBody] 
     AuthenticateModel model)
     {
       //var username = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\').Last();
       var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

       model.UserNameOrEmailAddress = username;
       var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(
           model.UserNameOrEmailAddress,
           model.Password,
           null
       );

       var accessToken = CreateAccessToken(CreateJwtClaims(loginResult.Identity));

       return new AuthenticateResultModel
       {
           AccessToken = accessToken,
           EncryptedAccessToken = GetEncrpyedAccessToken(accessToken),
           ExpireInSeconds = (int)_configuration.Expiration.TotalSeconds,
           UserId = loginResult.User.Id
       };
   }
   ```
7. Sending dummy username and password from login.service.ts:

   ```
   authenticate(finallyCallback?: () => void): void {
   finallyCallback = finallyCallback || (() => { });

   //Dummy data
   this.authenticateModel.userNameOrEmailAddress = "DummyUsername";
   this.authenticateModel.password = "DummyPassword";

   this._tokenAuthService
       .authenticate(this.authenticateModel)
       .finally(finallyCallback)
       .subscribe((result: AuthenticateResultModel) => {
           this.processAuthenticateResult(result);
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: i have been through this pain.  in summary i ended up using external auth provider.  in the ext auth i used directory services to authenticate against Act Directory. I retrieved some useful things from the claims like names, phone, email etc. I save/create user in db.  But always using dummy password.  so in the end i had to still ask user to login using their windows credentials.

Comment: @aaron Do you have any trick like other cases to get this sorted?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Windows Authentication.

Comment: This might not be possible because user doesn't access the Host application directly. Because of that Host application cannot authenticate user via Windows Auth I guess.