# External Authentication with boilerplate ASP.Net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to implement external logins with [Asp.Net Core 2.0](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates).

For external authentication boilerplate provide a class name ExternalLoginProviderInfo.cs

```
 public class ExternalLoginProviderInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }

    public Type ProviderApiType { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone tell me what is this providerApiType? What type we have to give it for facebook? What is its purpose? Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Nkosi thanks for your time but I am asking about this Type ProviderApiType?

Answer (score 0):

`ProviderApiType` is the type of class which implements the interface `IExternalAuthProviderApi`.

It is then used in [`ExternalAuthManager`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/d4129cfa90288cc1dadb3fa43b4721ec02fce93e/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Core/Authentication/External/ExternalAuthManager.cs#L43) to provide unified API calls across different external login providers.

Comment: ryan.c thanks for your time but can you please tell me which value i  have to give to providerApiType for facebook?

Answer (score 0):

To login the user thru official AspNet Boilerplate API (to have roles and other stuffs) you can use external authentication. Here is the a link to what you need

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication

Comment: john thanks for your time. Have you ever implemented this in boilerplate?

Comment: yes i did - more here...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820965/integrated-windows-authentication-in-abp-framework/48879621#48879621